# How to soql to get salesforce reports in some specified conditions?

Tags: soql, reporting

I know we can use soql to filter reports, like

```
q=SELECT Name,Id,OwnerId FROM Report where+ OwnerId = xx.
```

But I do not know how to get some reports that I do not own the execution privilege. Or some hidden reports.

Is there a way to achieve this goal by only using soql?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do that in SOQL is to use SCOPE that would help you to specify the data your SOQL query returns as below:

**allPrivate**

Records saved in all users’ private folders.
Requires the user permission "Manage All Private Reports and Dashboards" and Enhanced Analytics Folder Sharing. If your organziation was created after the Summer ’13 release, you already have Enhanced Analytics Folder Sharing. Available in API version 36.0 and later.

**created**

Records created by the user running the query.

**everything**

All records except records saved in other users’ private folders.

**mine**

Records saved in the private folder of the user running the query.

**organizationOwned**

Records saved in Unfiled Public Reports. In Lightning Experience, the Unfiled Public Reports folder is called Public Reports.

For example:

```
SELECT Id FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE OwnerId = ‘005A0000000Bc2deFG’
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_report.htm

Comment: Thanks, Ayub.  
Another question,
Can we get non-empty folders by only using SOQL?

Comment: You can get that but not in single query ..:(

Comment: However if you just query foldername on report, it's obviously return folder having report: [select foldername from report]

Comment: Do you mean no matter which method we choose, we should go through all reports before we can get non-empty folders?

Comment: you can use given query....but it would return duplicate names...you just need to consolidate using set or anything..

Comment: If we should fetch all reports first, the speed is not satisfying since we have about 20000 reports. We are looking for a way to fetch non-empty folders without reports involved since reports data is very large.